# Scapy doesn't sniff any packets when connected to WIFI

Tags: python, scapy

I'm just starting to learn about networks by myself with a book that a friend gave me. One of the first things that the book says is to download scapy and sniff 2 packets. The sniffing seems to be working thou `p` doesn't get any packets. This problem seems to be only on my computer and only when connected to WiFi (Ethernet works fine). I followed the book's instructions exactly. This is what the instruction said to write after opening scapy (in order to make sure that everything is working smoothly) :

```
>>> p = sniff(count = 2)
>>> p.show()
```

My code gets stuck after the first line.

Comment: did you set the conf.iface to wlan0?

Comment: Does this FAQ from scapy docs help? https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html?highlight=sniff#i-can-t-sniff-inject-packets-in-monitor-mode

Comment: just edited the question to be more detailed because I didn't understand a thing from your suggestions (not saying they'r bad, just that I'm a beginner)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.